# Can IBM-Watson infer from the context of sentences?

Tags: nlp, ibm-watson

I mean, for example, when we say some things to describe a scene, Can Watson understand how that scene is or look like? Cyc cop tried to design common sense for AI, like understanding and inferring from sentences from knowledge base systems, but Watson uses statistical methods for Natural Language Processing (NLP). Cyc Corp believes, with statistical analysis cannot make AI to infer and we need underlying knowledge to infer.

Comment: Very broad. Yes you can get some context (sentiments, objects, etc) from any piece of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IBM Watson Natural Language Classifier](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/nl-classifier.html) to use the contextual information within a sentence to place it in a particular class. For example if you have 100 different "types" of scene (outdoors, beach, mountain, indoor, urban etc) you could create a classifier that recognises the different descriptions and is able to correctly categorise sentences it has not seen before into their respective scene type.

NLC is a machine learning system, not just statistical analysis so it is able to learn how particular word and phrases relate to a particular type of scene and also understands the links between similar words using modern nlp techniques (i.e. Word vectors)

The drawback of this approach is that you need to build a set of scene descriptions and their respective type in order to train the classifier (probably 5-10 samples of each type) which can be a time consuming task. However this approach does scale up nicely (if you want to be able to recognise a new scene type you just need some examples of how you might describe it)